# Adding Chapters to .m4v/.mp4 Files

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, video-processing, core-media

I want to add chapter markers to my video and playback it like default movie app in iphone. Is there any code or library in ios to do that.

Comment: You want code for adding chapter markers? Or for playing back the file? Or both?

Comment: both, write and read, thanks.